# How to Implement a POST Request in Spring Boot Where the Client Provides a Unique ID?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I’m working on a Spring Boot application where I need to implement a POST request for creating a new Book object. The unique identifier (nombreLibro) for the Book is provided by the client and it needs to be unique in the database.

Here’s the code for my Book entity and the createBook method in my controller:

```
@Table("t_catalogo")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column("nombreLibro")
    private String nombreLibro;

    // other fields, constructors, getters and setters
}

@PostMapping("/{nombreLibro}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createBook(@PathVariable String nombreLibro, @RequestBody Book newBook) {
    Book savedBook = newBook;
    savedBook.setNombreLibro(nombreLibro);
    try {
        bookRepository.save(savedBook);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(newBook);

    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .body("An error occurred while trying to save the book.");
    }
}
```

When I try to create a Book with a nombreLibro that doesn’t exist in the database, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I believe this is because Spring is trying to update an existing Book rather than creating a new one.

How can I modify my createBook method to create a new Book when the nombreLibro doesn’t exist in the database?

Comment: Without knowing the error it is hard for us to tell what is happening. Please edit your question and add the stacktrace for the error. Better to remove/comment the try catch block first. Also you don't need to have `nombreLibro` and `newBook` as parameters on the method, it is completely redundant. Either pass in just the `nombre` or fill it in the entity and pass just the entity. Another suggestion is to use an actual id field as primary key and add a unique constraint on the name. It will be much easier to create connections with other tables later on.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Spring Data JPA it checks whether primary key value (Value for the field with @Id annotation) to decide whether it should update or insert.

If a value is present it is an update. If no value is present it is an insert.

Since in your case `nombreLibro` is a functional field not a primary field you can create a new `id` field which will store a Unique UUID and a regular field for your `nombreLibro`.

When updating you can get the `id` value for your `nombreLibro` and use that.

```
@Table("t_catalogo")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Column("nombreLibro")
    private String nombreLibro;

    // other fields, constructors, getters and setters
}
```